# Convex Functions: Property Proof

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let $f\colon S\to \mathbb R$ be a $C^1$ function on a convex domain $S \subseteq \mathbb R^n$.  Show that if $f$ is convex then $(\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)) \cdot (x-y) \ge 0$ for all $x,y \in S$.

My intuition is that since $f$ is convex we have that $f(y) \ge f(x) + \nabla f(x)(y-x)$ and that $f(x) \ge f(y) +\nabla f(y)(x-y)$ and I'd like to use these somehow but I am not sure what the best approach would be.  Is there a good geometric intuition for this statement, and any major ideas that might help me in tackling proofs of further properties?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\phi$ is a differentiable convex function of one variable then $\phi'(t) \geq \phi'(s)$ whenever $t \geq s$.

Now let $\phi(t) = f(y + t (x-y))$, compute $\phi$ and apply the above result to $\phi'(1)$ and $\phi'(0)$.

Comment: This might be a silly thing to ask but was it just for convenience that you chose phi(t) as you did? When I looked at it I thought it was a convex combination.  Also couldn't we have a function where that first statement is not true?  For example where the function levels off a bit around t?  Or would any such leveling-off necessarily make the function concave in that region?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking. Convexity of $\phi$ and $f$ are basically equivalent (in that $f$ is convex iff the appropriately constructed $\phi$ is convex for all pairs $x,y$ and $t \in [0,1]$). The point is that all you need are the properties of a convex function of one variable, and the fact that $\phi'$ is non-decreasing is fairly standard.

Comment: I suppose what I'm asking is, how are we sure that statement you mentioned is true?  Are there no more surprising cases when we extend beyond 1D that might be missed?

Comment: Well you could try proving it, or look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function (under properties). It is not hard to prove.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I will take some time and create a proof.

Comment: @Stopwatch: Maybe look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81885/a-real-differentiable-function-is-convex-if-and-only-if-its-derivative-is-monoto

Comment: can someone elaborate on this answer please.

Comment: @Monty: $\phi'(t) = \langle \nabla f(y+t(x-y)), x-y \rangle $. Does that help?

Comment: Yes thanks ! quick response.