# $f(x)$ is convex $\Leftrightarrow f'$ is monotonically increasing

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

How can I prove that $f(x)$ is convex on an interval if and only if $f'(x)$ is monotonically increasing ?

• Let $\lambda \in (0,1)$ and $x,y \in I$. $f(x)$ is convex on an interval, if the statement  $f((1-\lambda)x + \lambda y) \leq (1-\lambda)f(x) + \lambda f(y) $ is true for all $x,y$.

• $f'(x)$ is monotonically increasing on an interval $I$, if $0 \leq \frac{d f'(x)}{dx}$ is true for all $x \in I$.

I don't have a problem understand this, with a graph it's quite easy to understand. But I can't manage to prove it formally, can someone give me a hint?

Note that I do have seen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81885/a-real-differentiable-function-is-convex-if-and-only-if-its-derivative-is-monoto), but since I can't use inequality proven previously it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:** Convexity of $f$ can be expressed as $$a < x < b \in I \implies f (x) \leq f(a) + \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b -a} (x - a)$$

or $$a < x < b \in I \implies f (x) \leq f(b) + \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b -a} (x - b)$$

Then $f$ is convex in $I$ if, and only if,

$$a < x < b \in I \implies \frac{f (x) - f(a)}{x-a}\leq \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b -a} \leq \frac{f(b) - f(x)}{b -x}$$

In fact, one needs only one of those inequalities to characterize $f$ convex.

**Edit:** Let $x \to a$ on the first inequality and $x \to b $ on the second inequality then

$$\begin{align} a < b \implies f'(a) &\leq \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b -a} \leq f' (b) \\a < b &\implies f'(a) \leq f'(b) \end{align}$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I understand these inequalities, but I don't know how to conclude that f' has to be monotonically increasing

Comment: One more edit then

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how $f'(a) \leq f'(b) $ helps me

Comment: Transitivity of $\leq$, that is:  if $a \leq b$ and $b \leq c$ then $a \leq c$.
 
And $$f'(a) = \lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}$$ also $\lim_{x \to a} c = c$ ,where $c$ is a constant.

Comment: But how can I use this to prove that $f'$ has to be monotonically increasing?

Comment: What is the definition of monotonically increasing?

Comment: See my question (point 2)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22878/discussion-between-aaron-maroja-and-christian).

Comment: enter the chat.