# Is my proof for $f$ is convex iff $f'$ is monotonically increasing correct?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

I am following up on [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3752312/proof-verification-f-is-convex-iff-f-is-monotonically-increasing). My previous attempt for the proof was wildly incorrect (my question was how that proof was exactly my old proof was incorrect) and I have now come up with a new proof.

I have to prove:

> Let $f:(a, b) \to R^1$ be differentiable. Prove that $f$ is convex iff $f'$ is monotonically increasing.

What I have for the proof:

> ($\Rightarrow$) Assume $f$ is convex in $(a, b)$. Let $a<s<t<u<b$. By Exercise 23 in Chapter 4,
> \begin{align}\tag{14.1}
>             \frac{f(t)-f(s)}{t-s} \le \frac{f(u)-f(s)}{u-s} \le \frac{f(u)-f(t)}{u-t} 
> \end{align}
> Since $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$, both $ f'(s) = \lim_{t  \to s} \frac{f(t)-f(s)}{t-s}$ and $f'(t)=\lim_{u  \to t} \frac{f(u)-f(t)}{u-t}$ exist. However, **applying the Order Limit Theorem** on (14.1) gives
> \begin{align*}
>         \lim_{t  \to s} \frac{f(t)-f(s)}{t-s} \le \lim_{u  \to t} \frac{f(u)-f(t)}{u-t} \implies f'(s) \le f'(t)
>     \end{align*}
> which shows that $f'$ is monotonically increasing in $(a, b)$.
>
> ($\Leftarrow$) Assume $f'$ is monotonically increasing in $(a, b)$ and $a<x<y<b$. Fix $0 < \lambda< 1$. By Exercise 23 in Chapter 4, we must show that
> \begin{equation}\tag{14.0}
>         f(\lambda x + (1- \lambda)y) \le \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(y)
>     \end{equation}
> Denote $z=\lambda x+ (1-\lambda)y$.Then, $z=\lambda(x-y)+y$ which implies that $\lambda=\frac{z-y}{x-y}$. Since $\lambda>0, z-y>x-y \implies z>x$. Also, $1-\lambda=\frac{x-y-z+y}{x-y} = \frac{x-z}{x-y}$. Since $\lambda<1, x-z>x-y \implies z < y$. Thus, $x<z<y$. Then, (14.0) can be simplified as:
> \begin{align*}
>         f(z) &\le f(y) + \lambda f(x) - \lambda f(y) \\
>         \lambda f(z) - \lambda f(x) &\le f(y) - f(z) - \lambda f(y) + \lambda f(z) \\
>          \lambda[f(z)-f(x)] &\le (1-\lambda)[f(y)-f(z)]
>     \end{align*}
> Thus, since $\lambda = \frac{y-z}{y-x}$ and $1-\lambda = \frac{z-x}{y-x}$, it suffices to show that
> \begin{equation}\tag{14.2}
>          \frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x} \le \frac{f(y)-f(z)}{y-z}
>     \end{equation}
> Now, as we take $z\to x$ on the left of (14.2) and $y\to z$ on the right of (14.2), then we have $f'(x)\le f'(z)$, which holds since $x<z$ and $f'$ is monotonically increasing.

**Exercise 23 in Chapter 4 in Rudin**:

> A real-valued function $f$ defined in $(a, b)$ is said to be *convex* if
> $$ f \left( \lambda x + (1- \lambda) y \right) \leq \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(y)$$
> whenever $a < x < b$, $a < y < b$, $0 < \lambda < 1$. Prove that every convex function is continuous.
>
> Hint: If $f$ is convex in $(a, b)$ and if $a < s < t < u < b$, show that
> $$ \frac{ f(t)-f(s)}{t-s} \leq \frac{ f(u)-f(s)}{u-s} \leq \frac{ f(u)-f(t)}{u-t}.$$

**Can someone please read over my proof and see if there is something that I did incorrectly? Also, specifically, is my usage of the Order Limit Theorem correct and is the argument right below (14.2) correct?**

[image]

Comment: You never showed that 14.2 held. All you did was say that since $f'$ is increasing, then there must exist points where the finite difference might hold

Comment: @AndrewShedlock From (14.2), (and doing the things mentioned right after (14.2)), it would suffice to show that $f'(x)\le f'(z)$, which holds because $x<z$ and $f'$ is monotonically increasing.

Comment: @User31415 I don’t think it suffices to show that, which is (I believe) Andrew’s point. If it sufficed, then there would be nothing to prove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: (reverse implication)

If $s<t<u$, then by the mean value theorem there exists $\xi_1 \in (s,t)$ and $\xi_2 \in (t,u)$ such that (since $f'$ is monotonically increasing)
$$\frac{f(t)-f(s)}{t-s} = f'(\xi_1) \leqslant f'(\xi_2) = \frac{f(u)-f(t)}{u-t}$$

---

**Forward Implication**

By convexity, for $s < t < u$, we have

$$\frac{f(t)-f(s)}{t-s} \leqslant \frac{f(u)-f(s)}{u-s} \leqslant \frac{f(u)-f(t)}{u-t}$$

Thus,

$$f'(s) = \lim_{t \to s+}\frac{f(t)-f(s)}{t-s} \leqslant\lim_{t \to s+}\frac{f(u)-f(t)}{u-t} = \frac{f(u)-f(s)}{u-s}, $$

and

$$\frac{f(u)-f(s)}{u-s} =  \lim_{t \to u-}\frac{f(t)-f(s)}{t-s} \leqslant \lim_{t \to u-} \frac{f(u)-f(t)}{u-t} = f'(u)$$

Therfore, $f'(u) \geqslant f'(s)$ when $u > s$ and $f$ is monotonically increasing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I only need to restructure my proof for the reverse implication based on your hint.

Comment: Take $\lambda \in  (0,1)$ such that $t = \lambda s +  (1-\lambda) u$ to get  $t-s = (1-\lambda)(u-s)$ and $u-t = \lambda(u-s)$. Then substitute into the inequality and it should fall into place.

Comment: Do you have any comments on my proof for the forward implication as well?

Comment: When I take $\lambda \in (0, 1)$ such that $t=\dots$ as in your comment above, how is $\lambda$ arbitrary (which it needs to be for the definition of convexity to be satisfied)

Comment: Also, can you please also elaborate upon how the order limit theorem part of my proof for the forward implication is correct?

Comment: Let $s$ and $u$ be fixed. Let $t = \lambda s + (1-\lambda)u$ be any point in between (when $\lambda \in (0,1))$.  You then get $f(\lambda s + (1-\lambda)u )= f(t) \leqslant \lambda f(s) + (1-\lambda) f(u)$ which is the definition of convexity.

Comment: In the proof of the forward implication you need to be a bit more precise.  I'll add something above to help you.

Comment: You might have a typo here: $\lim_{t \to u-} \frac{f(u)-f(t)}{u-t} = f'(u)$ in your last display since $\lim_{u \to t-} \frac{f(u)-f(t)}{u-t} = f'(u)=\lim_{u \to t+} \frac{f(u)-f(t)}{u-t}=\lim_{u \to t} \frac{f(u)-f(t)}{u-t}  $

Comment: I don't see a problem or typo.  We have $t < u$ and $f$ is differentiable at $u$ so $\lim_{t \to u-} \frac{f(t)-f(u)}{t-u} = \lim_{t \to u-} \frac{f(u)-f(t)}{u-t} = f'(u)$.  I'm not taking a limit as $u \to t$.

Comment: By definition, $f'(u) = \lim_{u \to t} \frac{f(u)-f(t)}{u-t}$, but $f'(u) \ne \lim_{t \to u} \frac{f(u)-f(t)}{u-t}$, no?Is there something pertaining to one sided limits that am missing?

Comment: No.  $f'(t) = \lim_{u \to t} \frac{f(u)-f(t)}{u-t}$. It has nothing to do with one-sided limits.

Comment: $f'(t) = \lim_{\delta \to 0} \frac{f(t+\delta) - f(t)}{\delta}$. Take $u = t+\delta$ with $t$ fixed.

Comment: Oh, I get it now! Thanks! One last question: Why did you take one-sided derivatives in the last two displays? Wouldn't your proof be valid even if you took $t\to s$ in your first display and $t\to u$ in your second display?

Answer (score 0):

Monotonic increasing means that the function $f(x)$ cannot decrease with increasing $x$, i.e. $f''(x)\geq 0$.

Define $h=y-x$.To show a continuous convex function is monotonically increasing:

$$0\leq\lim_{y\to x}\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)-f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)=\lim_{h\to 0}\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(x+h)-f(x+(1-\lambda)h)=\lim_{h\to 0}f(x)+(1-\lambda)f'(x)h+\frac{1}{2}(1-\lambda)f''(x)h^2+o(h^3)-f(x)-f'(x)(1-\lambda)h-\frac{1}{2}f''(x)(1-\lambda)^2h^2+o(h^3)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{2}f''(x)h^2\lambda(1-\lambda)+o(h^3).$$

To prove the reverse direction, just read the equations in the opposite direction.

Comment: It is not given that $f$ is twice differentiable.  Convexity if and only if  the derivative is monotonically increasing holds without the existence of a second derivative.