# Proving concavity of a function

Tags: functions, proof-writing, convex-analysis

> Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be twice-differentiable. Show that $f$ is concave if and only if $f''(x)\leq0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Moreover, if $f''<0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$, $f$ is strictly concave.

I have started working on that using the hint about using the property of incremental ratios of concave functions: so given $t,u,v,z\in[a,b]$, by looking at $u,v,z$ we have $\frac{f(z)-f(v)}{z-v}\leq\frac{f(z)-f(u)}{z-u}\leq\frac{f(v)-f(u)}{v-u}$; whereas by looking at $t,u,v$ we have $\frac{f(v)-f(u)}{v-u}\leq\frac{f(v)-f(t)}{v-t}\leq\frac{f(u)-f(t)}{u-t}$.

To be sincere, I have no idea of how using this stuff to solve the problem. Some of you have any hint? Or maybe any other method to proceed?

Comment: I'm sure that I read a proof of this on this site, or a proof of the opposite characterization for convex functions. Try to search the site.

Comment: @AhmedHussein I have looked before posting but I did not find anything similar. If you find it, please link it here

Comment: This is the one I'm talking about: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81885/a-real-differentiable-function-is-convex-if-and-only-if-its-derivative-is-monoto?lq=1

Comment: Ok, so I have just to reverse my inequalities and that works for the "only if" part of the proof. Any hint about the "if" part?